# deiconized jframe not working correctly

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to recreate the the default minimize, restore, and close with JButtons. All my code up to this point works as intended. The problem came when I added a button and an actionlistener for my minimize:

I have a button that minimizes my frame, but, when I deiconize it, things get weird. Specifically the minimize button is still pressed permanently (visually), my scroll pane starts bugging out, a button that moved text from one field to another stops working, and yet my minimize and close Jbuttons still work.

I have tried repainting and/or packing after deiconizing with windowStateListener, but it did nothing. I also tried setExtendedState() which didn't do anything different.

I have 3 JPanels in a border layout on my jframe.

Here is some of my code related to the question:

```
public class DataUI extends JFrame
{
JTextArea ta;
JButton b, b1, b2, b3;
JLabel l;
JMenuBar mb;
JMenu m1, m2, m3;
JPanel p1, p2, p3, p4, p5;

public DataUI()
{
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    ta = new JTextArea(5,30);
    p1.add(ta);
    b = new JButton("Click here to put text into label");
    p1.add(b);
    l = new JLabel("");
    p1.add(l);

    p2 = new JPanel();
    p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    mb = new JMenuBar();
    m1 = new JMenu("File");
    mb.add(m1);
    m2 = new JMenu("Edit");
    JMenuItem copy = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction());
    JMenuItem paste = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.PasteAction());
    m2.add(copy);
    m2.add(paste);
    mb.add(m2);
    m3 = new JMenu("Help");
    mb.add(m3);
    p2.add(mb);

    p3 = new JPanel();
    p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    b1 = new JButton("1");
    p3.add(b1);
    b2 = new JButton("2");
    p3.add(b2);
    b3 = new JButton("3");
    p3.add(b3);

    p2.add(p3);

    add(p2,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    add(p1,BorderLayout.EAST);

    eventmin eh = new eventmin();
    b1.addActionListener(eh);

    event e = new event();
    b.addActionListener(e);

}

public class eventmin implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
    }
}

public class event implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String text = ta.getText();
        l.setText(text);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DataUI gui = new DataUI();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.pack();

    gui.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

this is my first time asking a question.

Comment: Post an [mcve] demonstrating the problems. And we don't have access to your images, so for the `MCVE` you can just use text on the buttons. Chances are that when creating the ~MCVE` you will find your problem. I

Comment: You might try using `setExtendedState` instead of `setState` and check to see if the state by checking `getExtendedState`

Comment: I updated to include my MCVE. minus the import statements. I ran it and got the same problem.

Comment: `setExtendedState` work fine for me

Comment: You example works fine for (MacOS), what OS are you running?

Comment: I tried setExtendedState again to be sure, but i still get the same bug. Could it be because i am running the program from an external Linux server? I am using windows 10.

Comment: See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: that was NOT the issue at all. that was just me getting used to stack overflow. the hanging bracket is fixed. still the same issue.